# What does "autoresize = W+H;" mean in NSLog output of a UIView object

Tags: ios, nslog, autoresize

Code: `NSLog(@"[self view] = %@", [self view]);`

Output: `[self view] = <UIView: 0xca2bfc0; frame = (0 44; 320 588); autoresize = W+H; autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xca1d7e0>>`

I tried to `[[self view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 568 + 64)];`, but view's frame is still frame = (0 44; 320 588). So I NSLog the [self view] to see if there is some autoresize constraints there. But don't know what does the above notation mean.

Comment: To @RobertLevy does this mean that (1) there is some autoresize constraints added to [self view] or (2) there is some autoresize constraints added to [self view]'s super view. And what kind of autoresize constraints does W and H imply? Flexible width and flexible height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the log description of the UIView -autoresizingMask. Basically, it's the way you describe what subviews should do when the superview is resized. It's very powerful.

Your current rules tell the subview to resize width and height when the superview is resized, and to keep the distance above and below the subview static (in terms of the superview coordinate system).

Comment: Hi @amanhuipg This W+H make the view go underneath navigation bar for 20 points. This abnormal behavior happens even when I set it to W only (that is setting `[[self view] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];` in `-(void)init` method of the view controller that contains `[self view]`).

Answer (score 3):

You can read that as:

> This view will autoresize by stretching its width and its height.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your current autoresizing mask is set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`

Comment: Yes I guess so too :D