# UITableviewcell properties change on presenting a ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So, here is the description of my situation: I have various `buttons` on my view, each of them presents modals, or other views (via push). My issue is that when clicking on any button, the `UITableView` **properties** change and causes the UI to change.

I have tracked the issue up until this point :

```
2014-04-10 12:48:29.652 ClosedApp[5229:70b] (
    "<UITableViewCell: 0x10ad20530; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'Yes '; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ad20310>>",
    "<UITableViewCell: 0x10ad24610; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'No '; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ad24900>>"
)
```

After presenting other views and returning to the parent view, here are the logs :

```
2014-04-10 12:48:36.931 ClosedApp[5229:70b] (
    "<UITableViewCell: 0x10ad20530; frame = (0 0; 280 44); text = 'Yes '; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ad20310>>",
    "<UITableViewCell: 0x10ad24610; frame = (0 44; 280 44); text = 'No '; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ad24900>>"
)
```

I have double checked my code and none of it changes the during or after the `performSegue` method happens.

I request data from server using this code (it is called in `viewDidLoad` method) :

```
- (void)loadQuestion {
    NSDictionary *param = @{ @"token": engine->token, @"view_session": sessionId };

    [manager POST:@"?type=getData" parameters:param success: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
        if ([[response objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue]) {
            //some code here changing the content of the entire view, no frames are changed
            optionList = [response objectForKey:@"options"];

            [self.optionList reloadData];
            CGRect answersFrame = self.optionList.frame;
            answersFrame.size.height = self.optionList.contentSize.height;
            self.optionList.frame = answersFrame;

            //hiding some subviews here
        }
        else {
            //show an error, params are wrong

        }
    } failure: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Please check your internet connection"];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Now here is the code responsible for populating the table :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *option = [optionList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             @"Cell" forIndexPath:
                             indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [answer objectForKey:@"text"];

    UILabel *accessoryView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 30, 20)];

    accessoryView.text = [answer objectForKey:@"votes"];
    accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    accessoryView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    cell.accessoryView = accessoryView;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:247 / 255.0f green:248 / 255.0f blue:250 / 255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    return cell;
}
```

I have changed the way my code behaves from a static height of table that increases with each cell to a table with the height of 44*CellCount, and making the `UIView` size static and enabled `Clip Subviews`, under `[self.optionList reloadData]` I added a code to resize the `UIView` frame height to fit with the cells available, the code still behaves the same.

I have creating a new view for testing, same results, here is a gif of whats happening:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/26u0wkn2jm2y72v/damn.gif

Edit : after further investigation I noticed that even a `UIImage` properties are changed :
Before presenting a view : [image: before]  After returning the view : [image: after]

As you can see the size of the picture increased...

UPDATE : just to clarify things more, I tend to use the same variable names for the same object when possible so :

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *optionList;

@end

NSArray *optionList;

@implementation MyViewController
....
```

Comment: these link may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128220/uiview-not-autoresizing-subview, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377760/what-does-autoresize-wh-mean-in-nslog-output-of-a-uiview-object

Comment: To clarify your question, is it that the visual representation of the `UITableView` is changing unexpectedly or is it the data behind the table views or the association of the tableviews to their superviews is changing?

Comment: I believe that UITableViewCells are the ones changing, the long up there is for the NSMutableArray responsible for the data in the UITableView

Comment: I'm not sure how are you populating your table view. The code you have used should have been somewhat in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method from `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. Why are not you using that!

Comment: I am populating the table from the custom method `-(void)populateContent` called in viewDidLoad

Comment: @SAFAD sorry but this is simply wrong. `UITableView` gets a [`UITableViewDatasource` protocole](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) that you **must** use. Otherwise apple developers wouldn't care about doing such things.

Comment: @AncAinu Well, I admit that I was wrong, yet using the protocols gave me the same results

Comment: @SAFAD then I suggest you to revise your question with these protocoles, so people can focus on the real problem (cause it makes things harder to get like it)

Comment: @AncAinu there you go, updated, do you need any more code?

Comment: @SAFAD I don't get so much what you want, you wrote about *the issue now is how to resize the table to fit its contents*, can you explain ?

Comment: if your problem is still here, I would suggest you to answer or your bounty will just vanish for nothing ;)

Comment: @AncAinu I still have the problem i tried everything but it never goes..

Answer (score 0):

My guess from your is that you're trying to manually adjust your `UITableViewCell`'s autoresizing masks/frames while the table view that owns the cells tries to do the same.

You should not touch a cell's masks and frames but you can change other parameters like its background color and whether it should clip subviews.

Probably the adjustments and customizations you're trying to get can be achieved by modifying the cell's `contentView` where you are free to do whatever you want.

Comment: Then probably your issue has nothing to do with those log outputs.

Comment: then what exactly should i investigate now? I am out of options and the app is due for tomorrow..

Comment: It's hard to help as your say the problem is that it "causes the UI to change", yet no idea of how it looked before and after/correct and incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

What happened to the Tableview delegate methods?

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 { }
```

Your code is manually formatting the tableview cells without going through the tableview delegate methods (or did you just code the For statement to make it more readable?).

The reason I am asking is that

```
        [self.optionList reloadData];
```

is a trigger to run a series of Tableview delegate methods in sequence. this includes the CellforRowAtIndexPath  and there maybe some conflicting code somewhere. I believe if you did not code it, it will execute the default code probably wiping out your modifications.

I do not fully understand how the presence or absence of the last 3 lines of code affects your table view cells except that changing the frame size of an instance of UITableView usually require a view refresh and trigger auto_resizing as mentioned by @Rivera. The tableviewCell height usually gets its value from the tableview property ("44") and it should not matter if your table view is resized or not. Based on your logs auto resizing W (which I suppose stands for Width is active for the cells).

Comment: well now I am using the tableview delegate methods and still the same issue occurs, what exactly do you need to see in my code, I will ask for permission to share it..

Comment: is optionList a UITableView, an NSMutableArray, or something else, this command is confusing:     optionList = [response objectForKey:@"options"];  If optionList is the Tableview and not the tableview datasource, this is going to create problems, but if it is the datasource what is option list reload reloading?

Comment: actually no, I changed `optionList` to `NSArray` to hold the array of data retrieved from the server, so its not the `UITableView`

Comment: your reloaddata should be on the tableview, (you should be getting errors once you start trying to adjust the frame of an array) - 1 other thing - adjusting the frame based on content size works only if the tableview stays within the bounds of the view (I'm sure you know this) when it goes beyond you will get problems so you need to validate if its going beyond or not.

Comment: If you still can't fix it do a couple of things, show the header file definitions for the  "@interface statement", and the "@property" for optionslist and the tableview, in the .m file show all the tableview delegate methods and statements that affect optionsList and the tableview

Comment: would you please explain more this out of bonds issue? also i added a gif to show the issue

Comment: Is everything working as you expect it to work?   I viewed your screen print, what am I suppose to see there and what is it that you expected?   You changed the frame size to match the total number of rows so if you have 3 rows and it displays 3 rows it is working. Out of bounds means is you have 20 rows -  your UITableview is going to be bigger than your self.view screen - problem is you won't be able to scroll down to the rows that are beyond self.view.

Comment: you seem to have problems with your main view?  it does not seem to fill up the entire screen - is this on purpose?

Comment: that is not the main uiview, the main uiview is the one on the background with blueish color, it has a subview, a uiview with limited height, the table is in the bottom of this subview, having the width of its parent uiview and the height of a single row, what I am trying to do is to resize this table to fit its content, but as you see in the picture, once i switch to another view, i lose the height..

Comment: I have added more about this issue

Comment: I don't know if we are talking about the same thing - your link points to a damn.gif a screenshot of an IOS 7 iPhone with a pencil right button, a table view with 3 rows that says  Blue 0, Red 0 Purple 0.  .....

Comment: Based on your log the height of your cells remains at 44 your width compresses from 320 to 280 which may give you an illusion that the height is growing - but its not - , if optionsList is an NSArray it does not have a frame so your statements in loadQuestion does not make sense. If it is the tableview, your previous statement optionList = [response objectForKey:@"options"]; will effectively change the variable from a tableview to an item from the response dictionary.  At this point its already very confusing can you discard the statements that have changed and no longer relevant.

Comment: as I already mentioned, optionList is an NSArray with data retrieved from server, my statements in loadQuestion are self.optionList, its a uitableview @property, the logs are old but they seem relevant, I can't seem to be able to reproduce them, however I have the logs for the picture as I showed you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51023/discussion-between-paulo-and-safad)

Comment: Autolayout was turned on and off between switching views, thank you for baring with me

Answer (score 0):

It is very overbloated and confusing explanation of what's going on and what you're asking about.

There are two ways to resize view:

1. Use autolayout constraints and change the height constraint.
2. Set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES` for your view and setup frame manually.

As a side note that makes me think why your interface falls apart:

1. Cells should not be created that way, please read about [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and  [tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acellForRowAtIndexPath%3a) in particular.
2. UITableView is optimized to keep a fixed amount of cells being reused to avoid memory overrun. That's why you're suggested to use [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3aforIndexPath%3a)
3. Besides that you can calculate the height of your tableview if all of your elements have fixed height, therefore you can resize your table view upon initialization.

Comment: I am doing just that, and I am using the datasource protocol now, and it still does the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

The code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` populates 'option' but never uses it. Instead it is using a variable 'answer'. Therefore, each tableview cell should appear identical. Is that true?

There is not enough code exposed to identify what's wrong and offer a definitive solution; however, it seems you have been struggling with this for a few days so I will offer this advice... Go back to basics.

It seems you are trying to resize your tableview based on the number answers you have. You may have better luck just using a standard UITableViewController and adding header & footer views to it - but I'll assume you considered that and need the UI you've presented in the gif. At any rate, you should comment out all the code that resizes your UITableView. Just set it to be nice and big for now and worry about adjusting its size later. It appears that part of your code is broken because if you set the tableview frame to it's content size, it shouldn't be scrolling. You should set the background color of your tableview so you can clearly see it's bounds. `self.optionsList.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];`

Next you should eliminate most of your code/logic for populating the table. For numberOfRowsInSection, just return 10; and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath just return the same hard-coded values: `cell.textLabel.text = @"hello there";`. Comment out all the rest of the code in there. (btw: you shouldnt' need to recreate that accessory view since you are re-using the cell, just get it and set it's properties. Only create it if it doesn't already exist for that cell.)

You should now have a yellow tableview with 10 cells in it that all say 'hello there'. You should comment out every other bit of code you can on this screen so you can really focus on the issue at hand (your bug).

You can then address your model. Just create a fake model instead of using AFNetworking (for now). When your view loads; simply create a small data set.

```
self.optionsList = @[
   @{@"text":"some text", @"votes":@"1"},
   @{@"text":"more text", @"votes":@"2"},
   @{@"text":"diff text", @"votes":@"3"},
   @{@"text":"text ahoy", @"votes":@"4"},
];
```

Update your your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method to return `[optionsList count]` (as it should have earlier).

If you are still seeing swirlyness, comment out even more code!

Also, fix any warning that appears in this file.

Best of luck.